# Not able to create a release branch in a Bitbucket repo

Tags: bitbucket

[image: the error message]

When I tried to create a release branch from this repo, I got this error message. I verified the branching model is the same as other *good* repositories in the same project as attached in another picture. Nothing unusual. Still working with our SDLC team. It took them forever to figure this our however...
[image: branching model]

Answer (score 1):

disable the "push check" of the related repo.